# Store svg code in mongodb and render it on frontend

Tags: javascript, mongodb, svg, mongodb-query

I am trying to store a svg code in a document in mongodb. It looks something like this

```js
{
"svg":"<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>",
"title":"svg 1"
}
```

Problem is, when i try to save it into a collection, mongodb runs something like `JSON.stringify()` on the svg field and i get a document like this

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("63a7d593c9f420bc0ec25a40"),
  "title": "svg 1",
  "svg": "<svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\">\n  <circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" />\n  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>"
}
```

And because of this, it is not rendering correctly on frontend (android). Is there any way i can save it as a raw string?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just parse it on the front end and extract it like `object["svg"]`? Where object is the name of your variable and the "svg" is the key in the objcet

Comment: i get it, but how can i parse that string? lets say if i was using js on the frontend, i'm not able to parse it by JSON.parse

Comment: `{
  "_id": ObjectId("63a7d593c9f420bc0ec25a40"),
  "title": "svg 1",
  "svg": "<svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\">\n  <circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" />\n  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>"
}` 

Is this how you receive the data on the front end?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: Then just store it as a variable. Idk how you fetch the data but it is already parsed when you receive it from MongoDB. `const example = async () =await axios.get("your/endpoint")` Then just pull out your svg `example.data.svg`

Comment: yep i just saw that right now.